# SQLCipher error while adding libsqlite3.dylib

Tags: iphone, encryption, sqlcipher

*I am using SQLCipher to protect SQLite database with encryption. I followed this tutorial http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial, everything went well until I add libsqlite3.dylib framework. It returns the following errors when I try to build it:*

```
/Users/Mac_005/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DBEncryption-fdbqkpkwxvqmbpevfwgkwtypioge/Build/Intermediates/openssl.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/crypto.build/Script-9038ACD812DCAC96004FA0D0.sh: line 66: ./config: No such file or directory

Cp: libcrypto.a: No such file or directory

Cp: libssl.a: No such file or directory
```

*It happens only when I add the sqlite framework. If more information required, I’ll provide it here. This is my first try on this, so couldn’t really guess the problem!!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial states: "Make sure that libsqlite3.dylib is **not** selected as a link dependency." In other words, you don't want to add libsqlite3.dylib.

Comment: Aww... That simple?? Thank you!!

Comment: Actually, still I am getting the same error. But It worked fine before adding libsqlite3.dylib

Comment: Try to clear out the project:
1. Run a Product -> Clean on your project
2. Delete all the files under the derived data folder in your home directory ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

Comment: Ended up creating new project :).. But I am stuck on the encryption part.. Would you please provide any link? Thank you!!